# Javascript onclick inside a forloop scope issue

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create onclick event that will change the color of the div, so far this is what I have done:

```
for (var x = 0; x<question_details.length; x++){
    var question_div_id = document.getElementsByName(question_details[x].question);
    answer = question_details[x].answer;
    divs = question_div_id;
    changeColor(answer, divs);
}

function changeColor(answer, divs) {
    for (var y = 0; y<divs.length; y++){
        if (divs[y].id == answer){
            document.getElementById(divs[y].id).onclick = function (num) {
                document.getElementById(divs[num].id).style.backgroundColor="green";
            }(y);
        }else{
            document.getElementById(divs[y].id).onclick = function(num) {
                document.getElementById(divs[num].id).style.backgroundColor="red";
            }(y);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is this:

[image]

The onlcick event is setting up the style without any click event. I tried `.onclick = function_name;` and this produced a different result, although it recognized the click function, the style applied only to the last element.

The requirement is, when user click a possible answer, if it is incorrect, then the style of that element changes to red. If the answer is correct, then the style changes to green.

Could someone please guide me to the right direction.

Comment: Please have a look at [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: First argument to event handler is event object you can't pass arguments to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing the function and assign undefiend to onclick you need to pass a function:

```
function changeColor(answer, divs) {
    for (var y = 0; y<divs.length; y++){
        if (divs[y].id == answer){
            document.getElementById(divs[y].id).onclick = function (num) {
                return function() {
                    document.getElementById(divs[num].id)
                        .style.backgroundColor="green";
                };
            }(y);
        }else{
            document.getElementById(divs[y].id).onclick = function(num) {
                return function() {
                    document.getElementById(divs[num].id)
                        .style.backgroundColor="red";
                };
            }(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function changeColor should only check if it's the correct answer and then, change the color of the div.

In your first for loop, you need to add an [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to every div containing an answer. This way, for each click, it would allow you to check the answer.

It would be something like this :

```
question_div_id.addEventListener("click", function(){
    answer = question_details[x].answer;
    divs = question_div_id;
    changeColor(answer, divs);
});
```